# how to access connection string Class.cs file?

Tags: asp.net, winforms, connection-string, app-config

I am totally new to Windows programming so i don't know how to access connection string in Class.cs file as we can in web application as follow:

```
 public DataTable Client_Login_Check(string Email, string Password)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        object[] objParam = new object[2];
        objParam[0] = Email;
        objParam[1] = Password;
        return dt = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GL"], "GreenLight_Users_LoginCheck", objParam).Tables[0];
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        OutputMessage = ex.Message;
    }
    return dt;
}
```

I have added "**System.Configuration**" namespace...But still i am not getting **ConfigurationManager** in help. Please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from adding a reference to `System.Configuration.dll` in the project, you will also need to add a `using` declaration for the namespace in the file:

```
using System.Configuration;
```

Note:

You should be using `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GL"].ConnectionString` and have the connection string in the [`connectionStrings` configuration section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7sd233%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), not in the `appSettings` section.

Answer (score 1):

Add a reference to System.Configuration.dll, and you should be able to use the System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use App.config

add these lines in  tag

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="mystring" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial     Catalog=dbName;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
   </connectionStrings>

   <appSettings>
     <add key="Server" value=".\SQLEXPRESS"/>
     <add key="Database" value="dbAIAS"/>
     <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value=""/>
  </appSettings>

 <configuration>
```

in Name.cs file you can access by

```
string strconn = @"Data Source= " +   ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Server"].ToString() + "; Initial Catalog= " +         ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Database"].ToString() + ";Integrated Security=True";
```